# Erro de encoding (Non-UTF-8 code) ao rodar script

Tags: python, python-3.x, cmd

Eu fiz um programa bem simples, desta forma, no bloco de notas, e salvei como `Somador.py`:

```
a = 1
b = 1

soma = a + b

print("A soma dos números é", soma)
```

Depois disso fui tentar executar o programa pelo `cmd` e deu essa mensagem:

```
SyntaxError: Non-UTF-8 code starting with '\xfa' in file C:\Users\Paulo\Desktop\
Somador.py on line 6, but no encoding declared; see http://python.org/dev/peps/p
ep-0263/ for details
```

Answer (score 4):

Em Python 3, [o *parser* assume, por *default*, que o código fonte está em UTF-8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3120/). Então provavelmente você salvou o arquivo em outro encoding.

Eu fiz um teste aqui e salvei o seu código em um arquivo, usando o encoding UTF-8 e ele roda sem problemas. Quando eu salvo o arquivo em outro encoding, como por exemplo ISO-8859-1, aí ocorre exatamente o mesmo erro que o seu.

Então você tem 2 alternativas:

1. salve o arquivo em UTF-8 (no Notepad, basta ir em "Salvar como" e escolher UTF-8)

   [image: salvar como mostrando os encodings]

   obs: provavelmente o seu arquivo está no encoding "ANSI", que no fundo é o "mesmo" que ISO-8859-1 e/ou Windows-1252 e/ou Latin 1 (na verdade é um pouco mais complicado que isso, [leia aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19111140) para saber mais).
2. se não quiser salvar o arquivo em outro encoding, então na primeira linha dele, coloque o encoding que foi usado para salvar o arquivo. No seu caso, provavelmente é:

   ```
   # -*- coding: iso-8859-1 -*-
   ```

   Ou:

   ```
   # -*- coding: latin-1 -*-
   ```

   Ou:

   ```
   # -*- coding: windows-1252 -*-
   ```

   Mas só faça isso caso o arquivo **não** esteja salvo em UTF-8 (pois como já dito, UTF-8 é o *default*, então colocar `coding: utf-8` é desnecessário: se o arquivo já estiver em UTF-8, ele funciona sem essa declaração, e se estiver em outro encoding, não funcionará pois o *parser* tentará ler o código usando UTF-8). Se você escolheu a opção "ANSI" do notepad, provavelmente as 3 opções acima funcionarão.

---

Resumo:

- o Python (a partir da versão 3) assume que o código fonte está em UTF-8

  - se estiver, maravilha (nem precisa colocar a declaração `coding: utf-8` no início, pois este já é o *default*)
  - se estiver em outro encoding, escolha uma das opções:

    - coloque a declaração de `coding` no início, especificando o encoding no qual o arquivo está, **ou**
    - salve o arquivo em UTF-8

Comment: Eu pensava que o comentário com o encoding no início do arquivo era só para informar outros programadores sobre qual a codificação do mesmo. No caso, o interpretador do Python lê essa linha e se auto configura para ler o resto do código na codificação especificada, é isso? Se sim, essa declaração deve estar obrigatoriamente na primeira linha ou em qualquer parte do código? E existe alguma ferramenta para por essa declaração em todos os arquivos `.py` de um projeto, para não ter que ficar colocando de um em um?

Comment: @JeanExtreme002 Segundo a [PEP 263](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/), tem que estar na primeira ou segunda linha do arquivo, e não sei os detalhes de implementação, mas imagino que ele se "auto configure" mesmo. Quanto a ferramentas, nunca usei mas eu chutaria que deve existir :-)